# How to implement dictionary learning and compressive sensing to signal in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, machine-learning, compression, signal-processing

I am trying to implement dictionary learning and compressive sensing for a signal from an accelerometer sensor, however, I don't know where to go from here. Is there any tutorial/blog that provides an explanation, methodology, and code for both dictionary learning and compressive sensing?

**Edit 1**

I found the code from scikit learn

```
sklearn.decomposition.DictionaryLearning(n_components=None, alpha=1, max_iter=1000, tol=1e-08, fit_algorithm='lars', transform_algorithm='omp', transform_n_nonzero_coefs=None, transform_alpha=None, n_jobs=None, code_init=None, dict_init=None, verbose=False, split_sign=False, random_state=None, positive_code=False, positive_dict=False, transform_max_iter=1000)
```

What I want to understand is how to decide the number of components and alpha value? Also, how can dictionary learning can be used in the classification algorithms in machine learning? See the example picture below and link.

https://github.com/UmbertoJr/Compressive-Sensing-and-Dictionary-Learning/blob/master/CompressiveSensing_and_DictionaryLearning.ipynb

[Dictionary Learning from Signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncWrN.png)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend SPORCO. Is not only for signals 1D, also 2 or more dimensions, and you can use dictionary learning in standard sparse or convolutional sparse representation.
https://sporco.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/index.html